# Bootstrap-vue modal manipulate ok-disabled state in function

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I've set the default OK Button in a Bootstrap-Vue Modal to disabled true and want to change it when inputing something in ab-form-input. Calling the function works but disabling ok-disabled not. Can't get access to the property. Seems to be a very basic question but in the component docs in bootstrap-vue there is only the infor that state can be changed (true-false) but not how to manipulate via script.

`

```
<template>
    <b-modal
      id="component-modal"
      title="Add Component"
      @ok="handleOk"
      :ok-disabled="true"
    >
        <div class="container">
            <b-row>
                <b-col>Component: </b-col>
                <b-col>
                    <b-form-input
                      v-model="component"
                      id="new-component"
                      required
                      @input="enableOK"
                    ></b-form-input>
                </b-col>
            </b-row>
        </div>
    </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../../store';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleOk() {
      this.handleSubmit();
    },
    handleSubmit() {
      this.insertComponentClass(this.component, store.state.project);
      delete this.component;
    },
    insertComponentClass(componentClass, pid) {
      const path = `${store.state.apiURL}/componentclass/add`;
      const payload = {
        name: componentClass,
        project_id: pid,
      };
      axios
        .put(path, payload)
        .then(() => {
          this.$parent.getComponents();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
    enableOK() {
      console.info('enable ok fired');
      this.ok-disable = false; // doesnt wor, linter says "Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression"
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on here that are incorrect.

You're binding the `ok-disabled` prop to a hardcoded value of `true` in your template. If you want that value to change, you'll need to bind it to a variable that you can update in your components `<script>`

For example, you can update the modal's `:ok-disabled` prop to:

```
:ok-disabled="okDisabled"
```

Then in your `<script>` data function, add it to the return object (defaulted to true):

```js
data() {
  return {
    count: 0,
    okDisabled: true,
  }
}
```

Now the modal's `:ok-disabled` property is bound to that variable and we can change the value in the `enableOk` method like so:

```js
this.okDisabled = false;
```

**Note regarding the lint error**, the name of the variable you're trying to assign to `this.ok-disable` is not a valid variable name. You can't use a dash (`-`) character for a Javascript variable name. You can rename it to the property we created earlier `this.okDisabled`